# Ставится ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Почему в следующих конструкциях ставится тире?

*Как пожар — хоть увольняйся.

Тоже мне красавица — никому не нравится.

Тут функций всяких — закачаешься.*

Answer (score 4):

(1) *Как пожар — хоть увольняйся.*

(2) *Тоже мне красавица — никому не нравится.*

(3) *Тут функций всяких — закачаешься.*

А хотите **интонационное** решение?  Смотрите на предложение – и сразу ставите **тире.**

1. **А что еще можно поставить** – запятую, двоеточие или точку с запятой?
   Пожалуй, ничего не подойдет, а причина одна – **разная структура** предложений, разговорный стиль, для которого характерна  краткость и  выразительность. При другом знаке смысл высказываний не будет понят, так как  тире обозначает **разделительную** паузу.
2. **В книжном варианте** всё звучало бы так:

(1) *Всё похоже на пожар, так что хоть увольняйся* (следствие на втором месте).

(2) *Считаете ее красавицей, а она никому не нравится* (риторическое противопоставление).

(3) *Тут столько всяких функций, что закачаешься*  (следствие на втором месте).

3. **Вот и всё решение**: знак выбран, отношения между простыми предложениями в составе БСП определены.

Кстати, именно такие отношения  **определяются прежде всего** (они даже называются грамматическим значением сложного предложения), это основа  для всех дальнейших выводов,  которые потом можно найти в правилах.  Если, конечно, вам нужна **ссылка на правила.**

4. Да и с правилами всё просто, если **смысловые отношения уже определены**.

Открываете Розенталя (лучше пользоваться непосредственно **источником**, а не его пересказами, даже хорошо оформленными): [§ 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151).

Ищем  две темы – **следствие и противопоставление**. Да вот же они, п. 2 и п. 3.

Вот и **ссылка готова.**

Answer (score 3):

> Как пожар — хоть увольняйся.
> Тут функций всяких — закачаешься.

В этих случаях тире выражает **вывод/следствие**.

**[«Грамота»:](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire)**
§ 171. Тире ставится между предложениями, не соединенными посредством
союзов, если второе предложение заключает в себе результат или вывод
из того, о чем говорится в первом, например: *Хвалы приманчивы — как их не пожелать?* (Крылов); *Солнце взошло — начинается день* (Некрасов).

**[Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=301)**
3. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если в ней содержится следствие, результат либо вывод из того, о чем
говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова *поэтому,
тогда* и т. п.): *Я умираю — мне не к чему лгать* (Т.); *Вы раздвинете
мокрый куст — вас так и обдаст накопившимся тёплым запахом ночи* (Т.);
*Не было никакой возможности уйти незаметно — он вышел открыто, будто
идёт на двор, и шмыгнул в огород* (Ф.).

*Как пожар*, (тогда) *хоть увольняйся.*
*Тут функций всяких* [много], (поэтому) *закачаешься.*

---

> Тоже мне красавица — никому не нравится.

В этом случае тире выражает **неожиданное противопоставление**:
*красавица, **а (но)** никому не нравится*.

**[«Грамота»:](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire)**
§ 169. Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми
предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому, например: *Я вышел, не желая его обидеть, на террасу – и обомлел* (Герцен); *Я спешу туда ж – а там уже весь город* (Пушкин); *Хотел объехать целый свет – и не объехал сотой доли* (Грибоедов).

**[Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=301)**
2. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней выражено противопоставление по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз *но* или *а*): *Служить бы рад — прислуживаться тошно* (Гр.); *Чин следовал ему — он службу вдруг оставил* (Гр.); *Шить сядет — не умеет взять иголку; её бранят — она себе молчит* (П.); *Прошла неделя, месяц — он к себе домой не возвращался* (П.); *Я хвать за пояс — пистолета нет* (Л.).

Comment: Ваше мнение понятно, _Eagle_. Но — рассказываете о тире, а ссылку даете на однородные придаточные.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Спасибо, что обратили внимание. Розенталя исправил. Вижу ваши старые ответы, довольно толковые и лаконичные, а новых нет. Почему? Всё забито одним гиперактивным участником, а хочется почитать что-то толковые и лаконичное, как у вас.

Comment: Пару-тройку советов по оформлению хотите?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Давайте. Если знаете, как можно улучшить мои ответы, охотно выслушаю.

Comment: 1. Дважды обращаетесь к Розенталю и "Грамоте" и дважды даете одинаковые ссылки — это перегружает ответ (оформите их в самом конце). 2. Если ставите значок цитаты, то все должно быть именно так, как в цитируемом тексте. 3. По поводу лаконичности: обилие примеров затрудняет чтение и, собственно, восприятие _Вашего_ мнения. Приведите два или три — остальные можно посмотреть в ссылке.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Но ведь сами ссылки не занимают много места, например: [Розенталь]. Что вы имеете в виду? «2. Если ставите значок цитаты, то все должно быть именно так, как в цитируемом тексте» – но я же ничего не менял. Что я поменял?

Comment: В качестве примера. Откатите правку, _Eagle_, если мои изменения Вас не устраивают.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Спасибо, за предложенное оформление. Так действительно стало яснее. Единственное, я всё-таки верну ссылки (может встрою в заголовки). Вы сделали для удобства чтения, однако некоторые ресурсы требуют на себя ссылки при цитировании, из соображений аварских прав. Пусть лучше буду возле цитат. А в целом спасибо!